# symfony 3.1 routing {placeholder} default value

Tags: symfony, routes

I made a controller with a routing and tried a default value, the controller code:

```
class luckynumber extends Controller
{
   /**
    * Matches  /lucky/number exactly
    *
    * @Route("/lucky/number", name="lucky_number")
    */
   public  function numberAction()
   {
       $number = rand(1, 100);

       return $this->render('lucky/number.html.twig', array('number' => $number));
   }

   /**
    * Matches /lucky/number/{choised} exactly
    *
    * @Route("/lucky/number/{choised}", name="choised_number", requirements={"choised":"\d+"})
    */
   public function undernumberAction(Request $request, $choised = 7) 
   {
       $numberList = array();
       for($i = 0; $i < $choised; $i++) {
           $numberList[] = rand(1,100);
       }

       $final_list = implode('-', $numberList);

       return $this->render('lucky/choised_number.html.twig', array(
           'number' => $choised,
           'list' => $final_list
       ));
   }
}
```

The problem is when I go to    ***http://localhost:8000/lucky/number/*** it tells me: **No route found for "GET /lucky/number/"**
what's wrong here?

Comment: `/lucky/number`: It's the valid way to match the second route (with default value), but his first route matches first with the same path (test it by disabling the first route), so you could merge both actions to achieve it.

Comment: I tried it ,now when I try to get **/lucky/number** it work with the default value,but if I try calling **/lucky/number/** it will give me the same error again??

Comment: Yes, `/lucky/number/` is not a valid path to work with default value, the wildcard requirements: "\d+" in this case expects a number after slash "/...", so no matches. You should use `/lucky/number` but this matches with first one route too, so you need be changes because wins first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found around this is from **twig files**,and it goes something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/lucky/number">lucky number</a></li>
<li><a href="/lucky/number/7">choised lucky number </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the default value in the `@Route()` annotation options, not in the method arguments.

`@Route("/lucky/number/{choised}", name="choised_number", requirements={"choised":"\d+"}, defaults={"choised":7})`

See the [@Route and @Method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Ensure you are not running into the trailing slash issue as described here: http://www.sobstel.org/blog/symfony-routing-with-and-without-trailing-slashes/. The route annotation in my answer works as expected in my own tests, but due to Symfony routing, you cannot access the URL ending in a trailing slash.

Comment: This article is about symfony 2 ,and I am using symfony 3.1

Comment: That may be, but the issue is the same. I am using v3.1.5 and my answer above is working.

Comment: N.B. as mentioned above, you must browse your URL with no trailing slash. If you want your URL to work with a trailing slash, that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 2 annotations like this:

```
/**
* @Route("/blog", defaults={"page"=1})
* @Route("/blog/{$page}", name="blog_list", requirements={"page"="|d+"})
*/
public function list($page)
{
    return new Response('<html><body>Welcome to my Blog'.$page.'</body></html>');
}
```

I am using **Symfony 3.4**